# Pass default arguments to cargo run

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have the following binary crate source structure:

```
prj
 |
 |__config
 |    |___conf.toml
 |
 |___src
 |    |_...
 |
 |__Cargo.toml
```

So when performing `cargo run` I expect the following command to run `bin /path/to/prj/config/conf.toml`.

Is it possible to config `cargo run` in `Cargo.toml` so it passes the absolute path to the `config/conf.toml` *without passing it explicitly every time*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to config `cargo run` in `Cargo.toml` so it passes the absolute path to the `config/conf.toml` *without passing it explicitly every time?*

Not *exactly*, but Cargo *can* be configured with command aliases in its [configuration files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html).  For example, you could place the following into `${PROJECT_ROOT}/.cargo/config.toml`:

```
[alias]
runx = "run /path/to/config/conf.toml"
```

And then you'd just do `cargo runx`.